# Draw, Clear then Redraw issues Quartz

Tags: iphone, ios, drawing, quartz-graphics, quartz-core

I am trying to draw a graph on the iPhone, but I want the graph to be updated rapidly, so what I really want to do is draw the graph to a `UIImageView`, then when the draw method is repeated, clear the old drawing and redraw it.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)redraw {
    canvas.image = nil;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [canvas.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0, canvas.frame.size.height/2);
    for (float i=0; i<500; i+=0.01) {
        [self y:i];
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), ((i*200)-200), (y*200)+canvas.frame.size.height/2);
    }
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    canvas.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

This code works exactly how I want it to when called once. It show the following curve:
[image: Working well]

But when I add a timer to `redraw` weird stuff starts happening. I get the curve Shown in the picture above when the app starts, but then it instantly turns into this curve (the same curve, just seemingly more stretched along the x axis, and higher up (technically lower down) on the y axis:
[image]

And:

```
- (void)y:(float)x {
    y = sin(x - 1)*pow((x - 1), 0.5)*cos(2*(x - 1))*sin(0.5*(x - 1))*cos(x - 1)*sin(2*(x - 1))*pow(cos(x-1), -1);
}
```

Comment: I wonder what `[self y:i]` is doing and where `y` comes from.

Comment: I'm sorry, but maybe I'm missing something.  What is the point of `- (void) y:(float)x`?  It's not returning a variable and nothing is passed by reference.  Is `y` an instance variable?  If so, might I suggest you alter it to something like `_y` or `y_` to indicate that it's an iVar.  Are you using the `y` iVar anywhere else?  I only see it used once in your code above, in which case it doesn't make sense to have it as an iVar.  Just have `[self y:i]` return a `float` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you're doing your calculations on `canvas.frame` while you're setting the Graphics Context to `self.view.frame.size`.  Now perhaps both are set to be the exact same size (I have no way of knowing) but if, for some reason, those sizes are different it could account for the 'stretching' in the graphic result of your routine.

Also, you have some odd code.  At the beginning of the method you call `canvas.image = nil;`.  But later (3 lines down) you call `[canvas.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];`.  If `canvas.image` was just set to nil, there's no image to `drawInRect` (and why would you want to anyway if you're looking to replace `canvas`'s image).

Comment: Yes that was the problem, thank you. I am using canvas.image = nil to make the canvas blank, so the quartz lines do not overlap. Is there an easier / better / more efficient way?

Comment: Assuming that `canvas` is a UIImageView, then all you need to do is set `canvas.image` to the new image you got from the graphics context, you don't need to set it to `nil` first.    When you call `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` you create a new, empty graphics context, so whatever you draw in that context will be new (no overlap).